# OwnValues for Set and SetDelayed

Tags: evaluation, core-language, variable-definitions

I am unclear about the OwnValues for Set and SetDelayed.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
ySet = a; ySetDelayed := b;
{OwnValues[ySet], OwnValues[ySetDelayed]}

Out[10]= {{HoldPattern[ySet] :> a}, {HoldPattern[ySetDelayed] :> b}}
```

Let me clarify why using `:>` seems strange to me.

The Wofram documentation for "[How to | Create and Use Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateAndUseRules.html)" says

```
In[11]:= x -> 3
Out[11]= x -> 3
```

> By looking at the output for `x->3`, you can see that this rule does not do anything: the output is simply the rule itself. This is because rules do not do anything when they are alone. You must use a rule with an expression for it to be of any use.

- Since Rules like `->` and `:>` are used with `/.`, why do they appear in `OwnValues` since `OwnValues` has to do with definitions? There must be some implied assumption for using them.
- Why does it store them as `RuleDelayed (:>)` for both `Set` and `SetDelayed`?
- For `ySet = a;`, why is it `{HoldPattern[ySet] :> a}` rather than `{HoldPattern[ySet] -> a}`?

There is a discuss of this issue at "[Question on Definition and values of symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919284/question-on-definition-and-values-of-symbols)", but no one seems to know.

Why do I care? To properly understand and program Mathematica, one needs to understand the evaluation process. verbeia.com has a detailed granular outline of "[The Evaluation Process](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_3.html)" which is more detailed than the Wolfram documentation. Knowing how definitions are processed is important so knowing how Rule and RuleDelayed fit into the picture is necessary.

Comment: An informal and incomplete attempt to answer the first question: Exaggerating a bit, the Mathematica kernel can do basically one thing (and it can do that pretty well) and that is replacing expressions. The whole language (as far as I can tell) is based on the concept of replacements. Metaphorically, it is the kernel itself that calls `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` during evaluation. All the other functionality (like the concept of `Function`) is emulated from this basic principle.

Answer (score 3):

In your example:

```
ySet = a;
OwnValues[ySet]
```

> {HoldPattern[ySet] :> a}

If [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) were used instead of [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed), then the [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues) of `ySet` would change whenever `a` changed. For example, if we had:

```
ownValues = {HoldPattern[ySet] -> a}
a=1;
ownValues
```

> {HoldPattern[ySet] -> a}
>
> {HoldPattern[ySet] -> 1}

OwnValues of `ySet` should only change [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) or [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) is used on `ySet`. A better example demonstrating the difference between [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) is:

```
ySet = 1+1;
ySetDelayed := 1+1;

OwnValues[ySet]
OwnValues[ySetDelayed]
```

> {HoldPattern[ySet] :> 2}
>
> {HoldPattern[ySetDelayed] :> 1 + 1}

Answer (score 0):

This seems fine:

```
Clear[ySet, a]
{HoldPattern[ySet] :> a, HoldPattern[ySet] -> a}
```

But this suggest a problem if we were to use `Rule`:

```
Clear[ySet, a]
a = 1;
{HoldPattern[ySet] :> a, HoldPattern[ySet] -> a}
```